# Printing composed HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, for-loop

I've been sitting for a long time doing the relative simple task of converting a javascript object and printing it on a page. However nothing ever appears. Can anyone se any obvious flaws?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#some_div').html(render_lists());
});

    function render_lists(){
var data = {
    "1": {
        "title": "Top 10",
        "0": "Number one",
        "1": "Number two"
    }
};
            var result_html = '';
            result_html+='<div class="row">';
            var i = 1;
            for(entry in data){
                result_html+='<div class="four columns" id="pane"'+i+'" style="display:none;"><div class="panel">';
                result_html+='<p>'+data[entry].title+'</p>';
                result_html+='</div><div class="box"><table width="100%">';
                delete data[entry].title;
                for(key in data[entry]){
                    result_html+='<tr><td>'+data[entry][key]+'</td></tr>';
                }
                result_html+='</table></div></div></div>';
                i++;
            }
            return result_html;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Of course it doesn't appear, when it has `style="display:none;` set :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works, it's just that you have the div's hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/5AyAd/

```
for(entry in data){
    result_html+='<div class="four columns" id="pane"'+i+'" style="display:none;"><div class="panel">';
```

Comment: OMG thats correct.. I guess I've been looking for a more complicated solution. Thanks a million, you put my mind to ease!

Answer (score 0):

Change your .html(render_lists()) to .append(render_lists())